# Leaflet and GeoServer : get base layer images before overlays

Tags: leaflet, geoserver

Is it possible to tell Leaflet to ask for base layers before getting overlays, from a GeoServer?

The reason I ask is because a Leaflet map of mine is quite slow, and get about 704 PNG-images back from a Geoserver after panning the map, which takes about 1-6 seconds to finish. If the base layer would show up first, it would not looks so bad - at least it would not show grey background areas.

It is common that WMS-layers take about 2-5 seconds to load when moving the screen? How do you handle that problem?

**EDIT**

The slowness happen when I click on a layer group that have about 20 layers, and it returns about 704 requests with PNG-images that have a size about 2 KB.
My internet speed is about 90 mbit/s.

Comment: It is not common, but neither is using 60 layers.

Comment: The slowness happen when I click on a layer group that have about 20 layers, and it returns about 704 requests with png images that have a size about 2 KB.